# Increase the memory usage limit on Kestrel for .NET Core

Tags: iis, out-of-memory, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

With .NET Core, websites are no longer hosted by IIS but by Kestrel. My current application is crashing with an OutOfMemoryException while creating a ZIP archive larger than 250 to 300MB.

Changing the IIS application pool option `Private Memory Limit (KB)` to 0 (unlimited) did not have the required effect.

I'm looking for the correct option to increase the amount of memory available to the process to allow these files to be created.

Comment: Are you exposing Kestrel directly to the Internet or through IIS?

Comment: Through IIS, but if Kestrel directly is an option I could look into that. For now the focus is through IIS.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if Kestrel direct had the same problem, at least then you would know to target IIS or Kestrel. I wouldn't expose Kestrel directly to the Internet though.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? Any configuration that can be changed?

Comment: @LuísAntunes No solution, I changed the code to stream the ZIP to the client, so the memory will not grow beyond the critical point any more. Still a solution would be nice if anyone found one when streaming is not an option.

Comment: Could you stream to a temporary file?